# how to check the provisioning profile is installed or not in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have provisioning profile which works fine on xcode 3.2.6 and shows installed and when i test the app on device it works fine i have also xcode 4 on macbook how to see that provisioning profile is also installed on it or not

Answer (score 1):

in Xcode go to Window > Organizer > Devices , and see list of installed provisioning profiles.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/ProvisioningYourApplication/ProvisioningYourApplication.html

Comment: in xcode 3 it shows but in xcode when i open Organizer/Library/ProvisioningProfile then it list of profile and shows valid profile